# formula giving #value error (a value used in the formula is of wrong data type java)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am adding data from one sheet to another based on formula but for one formula it is not working correctly.
It is giving #Value error(a value used in the formula is of wrong data type java)

I tried providing data in diffrent ways like 1234, "1234", 123.4 but same error.
this is the formula I am using

```
IF(OFFSET('Data sheet'!R[-69]C[-14],1,0)="","",TEXT(OFFSET('Data sheet'!R[-69]C[-14],1,0),"#,##0"))
```

> In the below code I am just picking the formula from a cell incriment the row and updating the respective cell formula

```
public void cloneSheetAndEvaluate(List<Victim> updatedVictimsList) {
        for (int i = 0; i < updatedVictimsList.size(); i++) {
            int selectionFormatStyle = selectionFormatStyle(updatedVictimsList.get(i));
            Sheet clonedSheet = workbook.cloneSheet(selectionFormatStyle);
            for (Row row : clonedSheet) {
                for (Cell cell : row) {
                    if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.FORMULA) {
                        String formula = cell.getCellFormula();
                        String newFormula = formula.replaceAll("(?<=[A-Za-z])\\d+", String.valueOf(i+1));
                        System.out.println(newFormula);
                        cell.setCellFormula(newFormula);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is a valid Excel formula - as long as Excel is set to use "R1C1" references (see File > Options > Formulas). Also, this question (as currently written) does not relate to POI - only to Excel. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: The edit doesn't provide a MRE. I cannot copy/paste and run that code - and there is no data for it to run on.

Comment: What is the purpose of the replaceAll? That regex does not match anything in the formula you have show us in the question. I assume it needs to operate on a formula which does not use R1C1 notation... I suspect the use of R1C1 notation in the formula in your question is a distraction - and the actual formula (as seen by POI) uses A1 notation.